# Al abrir mi interfaz grafica aparece en un sitio predeterminado el cursor de texto, como lo quito?

Tags: java, netbeans

Me podrian ayudar a solucionar mi problema, cuando abro mi app la liniesita que aparece al escribir, aparece apenas la abro, y no se si me puedan decir como quitarla, no comparto codigo porque no lo creo necesario pero si una imagen de donde aparece predeterminadamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola revisa esto,es similar  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773132/how-to-unfocus-a-jtextfield

Comment: Eso lo puedes encontrar en la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) y también hay una pregunta muy similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21419251/remove-focus-from-jtextfields

Comment: Hola, gracias a Jhon Jesus, esto me soluciono el problema, era nada mas poner setFocusable(false);, y luego setFocusable(true); para que no se enfocara en uno.

Comment: lo mas facil es usar el metodo requestFocusInWindow(); este da focus a un sitio de la pantalla especifico para no molestar al espectador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no comparto codigo porque no lo creo necesario pero si una imagen de
> donde aparece predeterminadamente

Siempre es MUY útil poder ver el código fuente para poder rastrear y/o reproducir el problema en cuestion, es lo primordial, no hay por qué pasarlo por alto! :D

Usar el `setFocusable(false);`, sí, en parte podría solucionar el inconveniente pero se termina por quitar esa funcionalidad de poder usar <kbd>TAB</kbd> para navegar entre componentes que en tu caso necesitan de un *input*, ese es un escenario de lo mas común.

A manera de 'solución genérica' porque hay varias por ahí, el siguiente ejemplo muestra una forma de darle el *focus* a un componente en particular cada vez que la ventana ha ganado su *focus* (cuando se abre):

```
miJFrame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent evt) {
    miComponente.requestFocusInWindow();
    //miComponente.grabFocus(); //alternativamente
  }
});
```

Como en la imagen que compartes tienes varios componentes, podrías hacer que `miComponente` sea el botón de *Continuar* y de ese modo evitas que el `JTextField` ***tome por asalto el focus*** al inicio de la aplicación.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, tomare tu consejo de compartir el codigo, por otro lado, el setFocusable() no me dejaba escribir nuevamente, pero con el codigo de abajo se soluciono, muchas gracias!

Comment: Exacto, focus en falso prácticamente invalida el componente sin dejar siquiera que responda a un click con el cursor, casi como si se tratase de un `setEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se debe realizar es quitar el enfoque del `JTextField` mediante el método  [setFocusable(boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable-boolean-)

> [setFocusable(boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable-boolean-) Establece u obtiene el estado enfocable del
> componente. Un componente debe poder enfocarse para obtener el
> enfoque. Cuando un componente se ha eliminado del ciclo de enfoque con
> `setFocusable(false)`, ya no se puede navegar con el teclado. Se
> recomienda el método `setRequestFocusEnabled` para que los usuarios que
> utilicen tecnologías de asistencia puedan ejecutar su programa.

En este caso debes definir de esta forma para quitar el enfoque

```
 setFocusable(false);
```

Revisa:

[Cómo utilizar el subsistema Focus (inglés)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Comment: yo hize eso y la verdad no funciono ya que ya no me dejaba escribir texto ahi